# Get different default comment doc style in Visual Studio without XML tags?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've found out that Unity has a neat documentation in code without XML tags:

```
   //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key identified
    //     by the key KeyCode enum parameter.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   key:
```

I wonder if you can set up visual studio to generate this with triple slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation conventions depend on the documentation *generator*.

If you want to get full intellisense with your comments, or use a documentation generator like *Sandcastle*, you'll need to use XML comment-style documentation.

In the other hand, if you're not interested on supporting intellisense and it's an internal project (you're not going to open source it and collaborate with other developers), you're not forced to use *Sandcastle* and XML comments: there're alternatives. For example, see this other Q&A: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/net-documentation-generator-alternatives-to-sandcastle

BTW, the main problem with alternatives is that they won't support C#-specific items that need documentation like generic parameters, lambda expressions and many other details of C# syntax.

### I caught a confusion of the OP

After chatting on comments, I caught the OP thinking that comments found in metadata of assemblies are *actual documentation*. They're not: they're just regular *comments* and it's not the source of intellisense.

Intellisense gets documentation from build-time generated XML documentation files extracted from XML comments, if this build step is enabled in project properties in the *Build* category.

Comment: The thing is that Unity's docs do support intelisense so I'm wondering how is it done.

Comment: @user1255410 Intellisense in their own IDE or as part of Visual Studio?

Comment: @user1255410 In the other hand, are these comments present in their source code or you're extracting them from the metadata? I mean, you pressed "Go to definition" and you found them.

Comment: Ah yes, I extract them from metadata via "Go to definition". Does that change anything?

Comment: @user1255410 I got you! So, now Go to Definition to any .NET BCL type and you'll find the same comment style. This is part of metadata, but it's not actual documentation

Comment: @user1255410 Intellisense source isn't the metadata, but either solution's XML comments, or intellisense of assemblies is got from the XML file that can be generated as part of building an assembly. For example `MyAssembly` can generate a `MyAssembly.XML` file. If you include both files in a project, you'll get intellisense.